# List of companies that has Implemented their own cryptocurrency or Color Coins in their business?

Tags: business, colored-coins

Is there a list of companies that has implemented either their own crptocurrency or went with the color coins approach into their business? I'm particularly looking for non-mining related companies that went with the color coins approach piggy backing on top of an existing cryptocurrency. Either they used it as a way of points or actual currency in their business to buy products/services.

Comment: I believe you can't find the such list at the moment. You should study descriptions of the assets. There are a few (might be five) blockchains with assets "on top".

Comment: Right now I only know of bitcoin's colored coins, counterparty, ethereum, nxt, and ardor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too vague, like asking list of companies that use arrays in programming. Colored coins are programming abstractions(just a type of data structure) and when *truly used for a technical reason*(not for crowdsale) they are under the hood. 
(At work, I have used it as a mechanism to account for scarcity of a resource.)